# C# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, richtextbox, invocationtargetexception

I'm having this error when running my C# .net 4.5 windows forms project from IDE or exe, I have no clear or fixed scenario, and I can't find a clue in the exception that is being thrown. I want to know how to get the source of error and fix it, or at least handle it in a way that does not make the exe crashed! 
Below are the details of the exception:

**Message:**

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

**Inner Exception Message:**

> Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Inner Exception Stack Trace:**

> at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr
>   wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, EDITSTREAM lParam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(Stream data, Int32 flags)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(String str, Int32 flags) 
>   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_Rtf(String value)    at
>   TragTask.UserControls.CommentControl.SetCommentInfo() in
>   C:\TFS\Tragging\Tragging
>   Solutions\TragTask\TragTask\UserControls\CommentControl.cs:line 76
>   at
>   TragTask.UserControls.CommentControl.set_Comment(TaskMilestoneTimerAndComment
>   value) in C:\TFS\Tragging\Tragging
>   Solutions\TragTask\TragTask\UserControls\CommentControl.cs:line 49
>   at TragTask.Forms.frmTaskDetails.d__24.MoveNext()
>   in C:\TFS\Tragging\Tragging
>   Solutions\TragTask\TragTask\Forms\frmTaskDetails.cs:line 339    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object
>   stateMachine)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0(Object
>   state)

**TargetSite**

> {System.Object InvokeMethod(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)}

**Target Site, Declaring Types:**

> {Name = "RuntimeMethodHandle" FullName = "System.RuntimeMethodHandle"}

**Stack Trace:**

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()    at TragTask.Program.Main()

**Update**
After C.Evenhuis pointed out that this has to do with CommentControl.SetCommentInfo method, I thought it would be needed to add this method in my question (note that tb_comment is a RichTextBox control):

```
public bool SetCommentInfo()
{
    try
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();

        lbl_user.Text = "userName";
        lbl_dateTime.Text = mComment.DateTimeAdded.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        if (mComment.Comment.TrimStart().StartsWith("{\\rtf1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            tb_comment.Clear();
            tb_comment.Text = "";
            tb_comment.Rtf = mComment.Comment;
        }
        else
            tb_comment.Text = mComment.Comment;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utils.Global.ErrorLog("SetCommentInfo", ex, true);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.ResumeLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The stack trace seems to point towards "something wrong" with the data provided to a `RichTextBox` in the `CommentControl.SetCommentInfo()` method. What data are you trying to put in there?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I'm loading user's RTF comments. Some parts of the comments may be colored programatically in the code if they are preceded by "@"

Comment: @Saleem If you can get your hands on the data just before the crash, you could see if it also crashes in a new WinForms project with just a `RichTextBox` and that data. If so, you should be able to isolate the problematic part.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis sounds a good idea, will try it.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I updated my question with the suspected method, my RTF text should be in a correct format, and the bug with the same environment and parameters occurs randomly not statically, so not sure what's wrong with the method!

Comment: @Saleem I don't see anything wrong with method itself, and the exception does not occur until the `RichTextBox` sends a message after your code has updated the `Rtf` property (at least that's what I understand from the stack trace). I was hoping the problem was in the RTF data (ie. a problem with an embedded resource or something) but if you don't always get the exception with the _same_ RTF data, I wouldn't know how to approach this.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes the same RTF data. Ok, thx for your help :)

Comment: I got this error on reading a file which had a couple of extraneous empty lines at the bottom. I had to change my code to ignore empty lines to get rid of the crashing.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

Corrupted process state exceptions are exceptions that indicate that the state of a process has been corrupted. It's not recommended to execute your application in this state.

By default, the common language runtime (CLR) does not deliver these exceptions to managed code, and the try/catch blocks (and other exception-handling clauses) are not invoked for them. If you are absolutely sure that you want to maintain your handling of these exceptions, you must apply the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the method whose exception-handling clauses you want to execute. The CLR delivers the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses only in methods that have both the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute and SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes.

You can also add the to your application's configuration file. This will ensure that corrupted state exceptions are delivered to your exception handlers without the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute or SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute. This configuration element has no effect on applications that were compiled in versions previous to the .NET Framework 4 but are running in the .NET Framework 4 or later; corrupted state exceptions will continue to be delivered for those applications. The HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute is ignored when it is encountered in partially trusted or transparent code, because a trusted host should not allow an untrusted add-in to catch and ignore these serious exceptions.

Comment: if you're just going to copy/paste from somewhere else, at least provide a reference and show how it applies to this question.

Comment: Caught me in the process ;D. It's also from a commenters link, but just wanted to filter out all the rubbish for him